# Ball Bouncing off of Angled surfaces

Tags: java, physics

I am a writing a game in which a ball bounces off a line that the player draws. I am not sure how I should go about the physics of the collision. I have the detection part down, but calculating the new reflection angle, velocity, direction of velocity (negative vs positive), and those types of things are a bit confusing to me. Here is what I have so far for the collision, but it really doesn't work at all

```
public void calculateCollision(ArrayList<Line> lines) {
    Line line = GroundContact(lines);
    if(line!=null ) {
        System.out.println("Processing Collision");
        double newAngle = 0;
        double oldAngle =velocity.getAngle();
        newAngle = 2*line.getAngle()-velocity.getAngle();
        if(line.getAngle()<0 && velocity.getAngle()>0) {
            newAngle = 180+(2*line.getAngle()-velocity.getAngle());
        }
        velocity.setvX(Math.sqrt(Math.abs((Math.pow(velocity.getSum(), 2))*Math.cos(newAngle*Math.PI/180))));
        velocity.setvY(-0.1*Math.sqrt(Math.abs((Math.pow(velocity.getSum(), 2))*Math.sin(newAngle*Math.PI/180))));
```

Comment: Try using [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) instead of degrees. [`Math.toRadians(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) should fix it.

Comment: Also using angles is a bad idea (due to costly trig functions and the 360-degree fold-back); just use vector math